# how to make an api call to server which requires special characters using NSURL session?

Tags: swift2

I am building an iOS app with Swift2.0, XCode 7.2
I am trying to make an api call to:

`htttp://xyz.com/t/restaurants-us?KEY=someKey&filters={"locality":{"$eq":"miami"}}`

```
let endPoint:String = "htttp://xyz.com/t/restaurants-us?KEY=someKey&filters={%22locality%22:{%22$eq%22:%22miami%22}}"
```

When I try to create an URL using this string(endPoint):

`let url = NSURL(string: endPoint)`, a `nil` is returned.

So I tried encoding the string before trying to create URL:

```
let encodedString = endPoint.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

Now the encodedString:

```
"htttp://xyz.com/t/restaurants-us?KEY=someKey&filters=%7B%2522locality%2522:%7B%2522$eq%2522:%2522miami%2522%7D%7D"
```

But now when i create a `NSURL` session and send the request, I get an unexpected response from the server:

```
Reply from server:
{
    "error_type" = InvalidJsonArgument;
    message = "Parameter 'filters' contains an error in its JSON syntax.  For documentation, please see: http://developer.factual.com.";
    status = error;
    version = 3;
}
```

So if I don't encode the string, I will not be able to create `NSURL`. 
But if I encode and send the request, the server is not able to handle the request. 
Can anyone please suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare `endpoint`, you have already percent-encoded some characters (the quotes). When you ask iOS to percent-encode it, it percent-encodes the percent-encodes. Decoding the `encodedString` results in:

```
htttp://xyz.com/t/restaurants-us?KEY=someKey&filters={%22locality%22:{%22$eq%22:%22miami%22}}
```

Instead, you should start with actual quotes in `endpoint`:

```
let endPoint:String = "htttp://xyz.com/t/restaurants-us?KEY=someKey&filters={\"locality\":{\"$eq\":\"miami\"}}"
```

Comment: Yes, it worked when I started with the quotes. Thank you.